# with blue/green k8s deployments, switching active color doesn't make the hpa scale up pods

Tags: kubernetes

I imagine this will be difficult to put into a context people outside my organization will understand, as k8s architectures are widely different.

We use blue/green deployments for our services, and we use helm to generate the k8s objects to apply.

so when we normally deploy a new version, we generate the k8s object files, including the service, deployment, and hpa.  These are all "colored" objects, pointing to the new alternating role.

we apply the hpa and deployment objects, then do a rollout of the new deployment object, then we set the "role" label on the service to the new color, then set the "role" label on the service to the new color, and then we scale down the old deployment to zero pods.  In a normal deployment, this magically makes the HPA do its work, and it scales up to the minimum number of pods specified in the HPA.  This is all working fine.

Those steps described above are actually performed in two separate Jenkins builds, the first we call a "DEPLOY" build, and the second we call "SWITCH_LIVE".  The "DEPLOY" build just creates the k8s objects and does the rollout, but it doesn't change the active color.  The "SWITCH_LIVE" does that.

The problem comes in when we try to do a "rollback", which I thought we could by simply doing a Jenkins "Replay" of the SWITCH_LIVE job.  What this means in our context is that we simply change to the alternate color, which was the active color before the currently active color.  My theory was that when we change the "role" label and change the selector, the HPA of the now active color would kick in, and spawn the minimum number of pods.  What I see is that after we change the label and the selector in the deployment, nothing happens.

If I instead replay BOTH the "DEPLOY" job AND the "SWITCH_LIVE" job, it mostly has the desired effect, but the problem we have with that strategy is that the DEPLOY job does other things, like regenerating all of the k8s objects and the application configmap.  That isn't quite as minimal as I wanted.

I then discovered that if I just Replay the SWITCH_LIVE job and then manually reapply the deployment object of the new color, even though there are no changes, it suddenly jumps into action and starts creating the pods of the new color.

Although that works, I need a way for the SWITCH_LIVE job to do this automatically.  In the SWITCH_LIVE job, as I mentioned, I currently only update the role and selector of the service object, and I don't do anything with the new deployment object.  Is there something that would be harmless in normal operation that will "nudge" the deployment or the hpa to do what it needs to do?

Comment: On Monday, I'm going to try adding code that simply adds a label to the deployment object.  I'm thinking that any modification to the deployment object could nudge it, but this is all still a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, that had no effect. Applying the entire deployment object did it, but that's not really practical.

Comment: We now have a minimal solution that works. We found that scaling up the deployment to one replica "wakes it up" and makes it scale up to the minimum replicas specified in the HPA. This is only based on experimentation, I can't find any documentation that says to do this.